# Making a page respond to touch

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the [canvas-photo](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-photo) but unable to make it useful for mobile/tabs.

Can you please guide me how to make this script respond to touch events. Also my Android Stock Browser crashed while opening the script.

Check the [demo](http://www.ernestdelgado.com/public-tests/canvasphoto/demo/canvas.html) here.

Comment: Have you tried using `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events yet?

Comment: I am trying now. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use something like this

```
var touchdevice = ('ontouchstart' in window);
var START_EVENT = touchdevice ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
var MOVE_EVENT = touchdevice ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove';
var END_EVENT = touchdevice ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';
```

And use it in code like this:

```
$('#something1').on(START_EVENT, function (event) {
  dosomething1(event);
});
$('#something2').on(END_EVENT, function (event) {
  dosomething2(event);
});
$('#something3').on(MOVE_EVENT, function (event) {
  dosomething3(event);
})
```

This will switch automatically between 'mouse' and 'touch' events

Comment: I will test and let you know soon. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed but performance issue remains. The drag event is delayed by couple of seconds.